# How to recover the Linux password

Tags: linux

In my PC, Linux is already installed and I forgot the password. I want to recover my Linux system password. How can I do it, step by step?

Answer (score 12):

There is no way to recover a password.

You can boot a different installation (e.g. from DVD), mount the partition with /etc/shadow and clear the password (set it to the empty string).  You can also try to run a password cracker on the file if you really need to know what it was.

Comment: +1 for the recovery vs reset distinction, though i think in this case the OP really wanted access to the system rather than actually "recovering" as such.

Comment: @Sirex: Will be interesting to see which, if ANY answer gets accepted. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Your system password? Do you mean the [root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_user) password?

Assuming you still have your password and you are in the [sudoer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) list, you can set a new root password by running `passwd` as root. Something like

```
sudo passwd
```

Comment: this is the easiest way if the user is in the sudoers list. It should get more upvotes.

Answer (score 8):

`init=/bin/bash` is by far NOT the easiest way to do this. Boot into single user mode.

From the boot loader, instead of `init=/bin/bash`, just add the word "single" (without quotes).

The system will boot up as usual but drop you to a Bash prompt never asking you for a password and already having mounted the system as rw. Then reset your password with 
the [passwd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd_%28command%29) command.

When you're done run

```
init 3
```

for CLI startup

or

```
init 5
```

for GUI.

No mounting, remounting, rebooting, booting from live CDs or distributions are needed when done.

Comment: Many linux distro do ask for the root password when you boot single. It depends on the settings in `/etc/inittab`, I think the 'secure'/'unsecure' line.

Comment: -1, ditto to @lorenzog's comment

Answer (score 6):

Fastest way is to pass the parameter `init=/bin/bash` to the boot loader (see an example [here](http://www.securitypronews.com/it/operatingsystems/spn-22-20040209LostRootPasswordLinux.html)). That would give you a root console pretty much immediately, now `mount -a` and `mount -o remount,rw /` to get access to the system. Finally, a `passwd` command should allow you to set the root password.

Second option (since nowadays linux distro need a ramdisk with drivers when they start) is to boot with a live distro, then mount your linux partition somewhere (a-la `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`), mount also `/proc` and `/dev` (devfs usually) into the new partition (`mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc` and `mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`). Finally, `chroot /mnt` and `mount -a` should give you your system back. Now, sometimes live distro see your hard disk as `sd` (the old SCSI mapper, now used for SATA disks), so you might end up with `/dev/hda` mapped to `/dev/sda`. That were the case you need to mount by hand all that you find in your `/mnt/etc/fstab` file. Once that's done you can try the `chroot` again, and then `passwd`.

If you find this complicated learn the lesson: (1) don't use root (2) don't use root (3) use sudo

Comment: +1 since this is a method that works on linuxes that have broken the single user mode.